# Reading arbitrarily length messages? How do you know your finished

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

**EDIT!
Just read that read will block until the buffer is full. How on earth to I receive smaller packets with out having to send 1MB (my max buffer length) each time?** What If I want to send arbitrarily length messages?

In Java you seem to be able to just send a char array without any worries. But in C++ with the boost sockets I seem to either have to keep calling `socket.read(...)` until I think I have everything or send my full buffer length of data which seems wasteful.

Old original question for context.

> Yet again boost sockets has me completely stumped. I am using
>   `boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket;` I
>   used the boost SSL example for guidance but I have dedicated a thread
>   to it rather than having the async calls.
>
> The first `socket.read_some(...)` of the socket is fine and it reads
>   all the bytes. After that it reads 1 byte and then all the rest on the
>   next `socket.read_some(...)` which had me really confused. I then
>   noticed that read_some typically has this behaviour. So I moved to
>   `boost::asio::read` as socket does have a member function read which
>   surprised me. However noticed boost::asio has a read function that
>   takes a socket and buffer. However it is permanently blocking.
>
> ```
> //read blocking data method
> //now
> bytesread = boost::asio::read(socket,buffer(readBuffer, max_length)); << perminatly blocks never seems to read.
> //was 
> //bytesread =  socket.read_some(buffer(readBuffer, max_length)); << after the 1st read it will always read one byte and need another
> ```
>
> socket.read_some(...) call to read the rest.
>
> What do I need to do make `boost::asio::read(...)` work?
>
> note .. I have used wireshark to make sure that the server is not
>   sending the data broken up. The server is not faulty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read with `read_some()` in a loop merging the buffers until you get a complete application message. Assume you can get back anything between 1 byte and full length of your buffer.

Regarding "knowing when you are finished" - that goes into your *application level protocol*, which could use either delimited messages, fixed length messages, fixed length headers that tell payload length, etc.

Comment: Wont that block at the end and leave my thread deadlocked? Or do I define something to determine the end of my message like null terminating a string?